# text Editor With image for java web application

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, struts2

I  have java web application project and i am using struts2,hibernate,javascript,jquery. I want to make text editor and also insert image using drag and drop.how it is possible any buddy guide me.

Comment: Do You mean that you want to be able to insert an image into the text?

Comment: yes image with text. I want to write image with content.

Comment: Both too broad and asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Where did you use struts2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several rich-text javascript editors available:

- [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/),
- [NicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com),
- [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)

You can also use the contentEditable attribute and add your own buttons to insert images and other stuff.

Comment: @SurendraSingh of course: don't we all do? I believe the NicEdit is.

Comment: could we save text area as a pdf format.and save option is there.

Comment: @SurendraSingh Nope! it's HTML